# Alamofire Background Service, Global Manager? Global Authorisation Header?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Can anyone tell me how to use the Alamofire background service correctly?

My attempts are:

Login View Controller

```
// Create a global variable for the manager
var manager = Alamofire.Manager()
var configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration()


class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    // set the configuration for the manager
          configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier("com.xxx.app.backgroundService")
          configuration.sharedContainerIdentifier = "com.xxx.app.backgroundService"
}
```

Now creating my login attempt, when successful go to the MainViewController and do here some more Requests.

```
 manager.request(.POST, "\(serviceUrl)public/service/authenticate", parameters: ["email": txtEmail.text!, "password": txtPassword.text!]) {
   ......
}
```

Here ill get my token for all requests, so ill add the to my global configuration:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
     if let token: AnyObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("token") {
        configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"]
        manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
    }
}
```

But now when ill logout and login again - ill get the following errors:

```
Warning: A background URLSession with identifier xxx.xxx.app.backgroundService already exists!
```

And the app crashes with:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Task created in a session that has been invalidated'
*** First throw call stack:
```

So i really dont know how do use the background-service to get the following result:

At login attempt, i dont need to add an authentication header. But then, i would like to add it to every request. All requests should run as background service.

Can anyone help me out, how to solve that in a correct way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have multiple problems. The first is that you need to pass the `configuration` object into the `Manager` initializer. Otherwise you are not using the `configuration` for the underlying URL session in the `Manager` instance.

The second issue is that you should NOT set header values on a configuration after it has been applied to a `Manager` instance. The Apple docs specifically call this out. We also call this out in our [README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#http-headers). If you need to deal with authorization tokens, you need to pass them as a header attached to the actual request.

---

### Update #1

Here's a small example showing how you could create a `Manager` instance that could be used globally.

```
class NetworkManager {
    var authToken = "1234" // You'll need to update this as necessary

    let manager: Manager = {
        let configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration = {
            let identifier = "com.company.app.background-session"
            let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier(identifier)
            return configuration
        }()

        return Manager(configuration: configuration)
    }()

    static let sharedInstance = NetworkManager()
}

class ExampleClass {
    func startNetworkRequest() {
        let headers = ["Authorization": NetworkManager.sharedInstance.authToken]

        NetworkManager.sharedInstance.manager.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", headers: headers)
            .responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response)
            }
    }
}
```

You'll still need to work out how to update the `authToken` when it expires, but this shows one way how you could use your `manager` instance throughout your codebase.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can u give me some more information? - Where should i init the Manager variable, is that a global variable (outside a class?) - Or should i make the configuration outside any class, to make in global? It the Readme there is an information that i should attach my token to the global configuration, so it gets pushed to every request. So to help me out it would be great to have a short example where i should create my configuration, where i should set my background identifier, and where i should update my configuration (in every class where i would like to use alamofire?)

Comment: There is NOT information in the README that you should attach tokens to every request using your configuration. It explicitly points out NOT to do that.

Comment: What did that mean then: "For HTTP headers that do not change, it is recommended to set them on the NSURLSessionConfiguration so they are automatically applied to any NSURLSessionTask created by the underlying NSURLSession." ?

Comment: You token will change over time. Therefore, it should not be attached to the configuration.

Comment: @cnoon what is the way to revalidate the session ? like if u invalidateAndCancel() the shared session and try to request again u wont be able to that why is that so ?

Comment: After a session has been invalidated, you no longer can execute requests on it. You MUST make a new one.