# How to revalidate the session once it is invalidated Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, session, alamofire, tvos

The use of invalidateAndCancel() comes up with another problem which is to reinitialize the session again if u need to use it again. After searching on this problem i got the answer of Cnoon's [Alamofire Background Service, Global Manager? Global Authorisation Header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547151/alamofire-background-service-global-manager-global-authorisation-header). Tried creating the manager but when it is called it never re-initialize the value, to anticipate this problem i did a small cheat i tried giving my session new name each time.

```
    func reset() -> Manager {

            let configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration = {
                let identifier = "com.footbits.theartgallery2.background-session\(sessionCount)"
                let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier(identifier)
                return configuration
            }()

            return Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
        }


func cancelAllRequests() {

   manager.session.invalidateAndCancel()
   sessionCount += 1
   manager = reset()

}
```

Now i am curious of what is happening in background like the previous session is still there or has been removed by alamofire because if it is still there how many session can i create and what will be the after affect? because i tried:

```
manager.session.resetWithCompletionHandler {

            print("Session reset")
        }
```

it doesnt work.

Comment: Because at that particular moment i want it to be finished and there is a possibility that i'll start with a new request the next time.

Comment: So i already tried that it never comes into effect immediately. I dont know what is the science behind this. Also, Cnoon's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999892/ios-alamofire-stop-all-requests encourages us to do that through invalidating the session and yes it works as well. Can u share something like how u r recommending it ?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but this info will apply to you (the reader) wether or not you are using Alamofire.

You can not revalidate a URLSession, for good reason: The tasks within a session will be told to cancel upon invalidation of the session. However, those tasks may take a while to actually cancel and leave the session. To prove this, cancel a session and retrieve its tasks periodically afterwards. They'll slowly drop towards zero.

What you need to do instead is create a new session with a new identifier. **Using the same identifier will cause the old session to be used and crash if new tasks are scheduled to it!**

For those seeking to perform background downloads consider using a `UUID().uuidString` as part of the identifier and storing the id somewhere on the device (Userdefaults come to mind), and generating a new uuid after every call to invalidate your current session. Then create a new session object with a new uuid and reference that instead. Bonus: This new session immediately will have 0 open tasks which proves useful if your logic is based on that.

Example from within my project:

```
@UserDefaultOptional(defaultValue: nil, "com.com.company.sessionid")
private var sessionID: String?

// MARK: - Init

private var session: URLSession!

private override init() {
    super.init()
    setupNewSession()
}

private func setupNewSession() {
    let id = sessionID ?? UUID().uuidString
    sessionID = id
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: id)
    session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
}

private func invalidateSession() {
    session.invalidateAndCancel()
    sessionID = nil
    setupNewSession()
}
```